# Select a value and set it in a variable in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

this is my problem:

I have a result of a SELECT that show me some value like first name and last name of a user.

Example:
Firstname = "First"
Lastname = "Last"

Now I want to get another value that is the result of another select (SELECT * FROM x WHERE y = z)
Example:
Firstname = "First"
Lastname = "Last"
**NewValue** = "true" (or false)

How can I do this?

Comment: do you mean select column in your select based on another select ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean something like this

```
 select Firstname , Lastname , (select column from another_table ) as NewValue
 from myTable
```

Comment: I have moved the "AS newValue" outside the parenthesis! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Firstname, Lastname, 
       (SELECT ColumnName AS NewValue
        FROM table_Name2
        WHERE (your condition goes here)       
FROM table_Name1
WHERE (your condition goes here)
```